# Is UITableViewController compatible with NSCoding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitableview, nscoding

When I try to get a h file that inherits from UITableViewController to conform to NSCoding, I can't switch views.

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*) coder
{
    [self init];
    return self;
}
```

Inserting the above code into the m file is what causes the problem. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Just calling `[self init]` can cause a lot of problems. You should override `initWithCoder` like that:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*) coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
    if (self) {
        // Call a setup method
    }
    return self;
}
```